# Compare two tables in excel across different rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an excel sheet with below data:

```
    A   | B     |    C  |    D   |   E   |   F   |   G   
----------------------------------------------------------
Apple   |Orange |Mango  |        |1      |2      |3
Coffee  |Tea    |Juice  |        |Apple  |Orange |Mango
1       |2      |3      |        |Rose   |Jasmine|Sun Flower
```

Columns ABCD and EFG are two different tables. I want to compare A to E, B to F and C to G but the problem is they will not be in the same order and there will be instances where it will not match as well.
I want to populate column D with "Exists" or "Not Exists" as part of table ABCD and say the same combination exists in EFG table. For example, for row number 1 and 3, it should say exists as these values exist in the second table in same order. All 3 columns need to match.

I tried creating a VLOOKUP using multiple references for the same but could not get it to work as its my first time. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried the below for only two columns but its giving wrong data: =COUNTIFS([A],Table2[A],[B],Table2[B])>0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS and check if the result is >0.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(E:E,A1,F:F,B1,G:G,C1)>0,"Exists","Not Exists")
```

[image]